# How to get columns types in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got this code in my view to get the columns of a specific table

```
$columns = \Schema::getColumnListing('posts')
```

So I made a `foreach` loop to get all columns' names. But now I'm making a CRUD generator so I'll need the column type to know which type of fields I'll make for it. The code above just gave me the columns' names. How can I get also the column type?

Update:
I searched for the file which contains getColumnListing method and I found a method called `getColumnType($table, $column)`. It returns a string.

I tried to use it but i got this error:

`FatalErrorException in MySqlConnection.php line 64:
Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found`

Answer (score 2):

I searched for `getColumnListing` method in the project and I found it in a file called `Builder.php` and in the exact above of `getColumnListing` method I found a method called `getColumnType($table, $column)`

I tried to use `getColumnType` method using this line of code:

`$type = \Schema::getColumnType('{{collection}}s', $col);`

But I got this error: `FatalErrorException in MySqlConnection.php line 64:
Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found` And this was because a missed package called `doctrine/dbal` which is not included anymore with laravel 5.2

So I run this command `composer require doctrine/dbal` and I got no errors anymore.

Thanks for @pari who told me to install doctrin/dbal.

Comment: welcome @ Ahmed if you found it is correct mark answer as useful

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
            $tables = ['tablename'];
            foreach($tables as $table){
              $table_info_columns = DB::select( DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table));

              foreach($table_info_columns as $column){
                $col_name = $column->Field;
                $col_type = $column->Type;
                var_dump($col_name,$col_type);
              } 
            }
```

Comment: Tried it before but I got 

FatalErrorException in MySqlConnection.php line 64: Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

Answer (score 0):

you can use getColumnType() method in your foreach.

This package is necessary .

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Error: Call to a member function getType() on string
`$columns` gets an array of only names of the columns

Comment: let me check again

Comment: I saw the class where the method getColumnListing() exists in. And I found a method called getColumnType($table, $column);
I tried it but I got:
FatalErrorException in MySqlConnection.php line 64:
Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
Can you help me in that?

Comment: what is the version of your laravel  ?

Comment: The newest version. Laravel 5.2